# Javascript onclick only works in chrome, not in firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, onclick

Please could someone help.

I have some social media buttons implemented on our website which work beautifully in Chrome but have discovered don't work in Firefox or IE.

The website is www.m-j-p.co.uk. When using IE or firefox every button navigates away from the site to a blank white screen, some of which display the function name in the address bar.

Tried the firefox console but doesn't give any errors or clues.

```js
 <script language="javascript">
    function tweetCurrentPage()
    {window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url="+escape(window.location.href)+"&text="+document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false; }
 </script> 
 
 <script language="javascript">
 function twitFollow()
    {window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=MedNeg", '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,height=580,width=380');return false; }
 </script>
```

```html
<li class="but50"><a style="padding-bottom: 18px;"  href="javascript:tweetCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Tweet this page" data-via="medneg"><div style="width:50px; text-align:center; float:left"><i class='fa fa-twitter icon' style="font-size: 28px;"></i></div>  Share Page</a></li>
<li class="but50"><a style="padding-bottom: 18px;" href="javascript:twitFollow()"><div style="width:50px; text-align:center; float:left"><i class='fa fa-twitter icon' style="font-size: 28px;"></i></div>  Follow @MJP</a></li>
```

Comment: 'onclick' works in all of them. What happens when you switch from the javascript-protocol in href tags to *actually* doing the operation *in* an 'onclick'? (I wonder if perhaps the javascript-protocol has been disabled in such..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run an onlick instead like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="tweetCurrentPage(); return false" style="display:block; float:right; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none">test<a>
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88z7u4kf/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="but50"><a style="padding-bottom: 18px;"  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="tweetCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Tweet this page" data-via="medneg"><div style="width:50px; text-align:center; float:left"><i class='fa fa-twitter icon' style="font-size: 28px;"></i></div>  Share Page</a></li>

<li class="but50"><a style="padding-bottom: 18px;" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="twitFollow()"><div style="width:50px; text-align:center; float:left"><i class='fa fa-twitter icon' style="font-size: 28px;"></i></div>  Follow @MJP</a></li>
```